# How do I install Windows Server 2008 R2 on a Dell Power Edge 2850?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2850, with an old PERC 4 controller.  In the installation wizard (using the latest Dell Server Assistant DVD), I run into a snag when trying to target my disk drive.  It sees the array, but says that it cannot install there.

Any ideas how to get around this?  I would like to be able to re-purpose these dinosaurs if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah!  Just found the driver I'm looking for [here](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=2684&l=en&s=pub&releaseid=R227150&SystemID=PWE_PNT_P3C_2850&servicetag=69NTP91&os=WS8R2&osl=en&deviceid=6395&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=4&libid=35&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=326367).  After loading it up, I could install to the array without any problem.